# pass props through navigation react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation, stack-navigator

I'm working on passing props through navigator. i'm having issues with passing multiple props from state to another screen. I've tried

```
passData(){
this.props.navigation.navigate('ListingAddressPhoto', {nickName:this.state.nickName})
}
```

This works but it will only pass one prop. I've tried to add more properties to it but the second page only reads this. How do i pass props from textinput and other components. I've read about Redux but I wanted to know if there was another route rather than utilizing this.

my components are below

```
<View style = {styles.inputdata}>    
           <TextInput 
            style = {styles.nickNameTextInput}
            onChangeText={(nickName) => this.setState({nickName})}
            placeholder={"Nickname eg. Cool Location"} 
            color={"black"}
            placeholderTextColor={"grey"}/> 
        </View> 
        <View style = {styles.reginput}>    
          <TextInput 
            style = {styles.nickNameTextInput}
            onChangeText={(hourlyRate) => this.setState({hourlyRate})}
            placeholder={"hourly rate"} 
            color={"black"}
            keyboardType='numeric'
            placeholderTextColor={"grey"}/> 
        </View> 
        <View style={styles.descriptionTextBox}>
          <TextInput 
            style = {styles.nickNameTextInput}
            multiline={true}
            borderColor={"black"}
            onChangeText={(description) => this.setState({description})}
            placeholder={"Describe your spot"} 
            color={"black"}
            placeholderTextColor={"grey"}/> 
        </View>
```

I'm taking all the data and saving it to state from my properties in my constructor. Then i want to pass it to the next screen which then I'll upload it to Firebase.

Comment: can you share the code where you're accessing it?

Comment: just added more code. please let me know if you need anything else. thanks for your help in advanced!

Comment: You passData is called on a click when all your state variables are set right? 

Just use {nickName:this.state.nickName,hourlyRate:this.state.hourlyRate,description: this.state.description} as a second argument to .navigate function

Comment: Thanks Pavan I figured it out. closing this out.